# virtualenv and VIRTUAL_ENV keyword

Tags: python, virtualenv

After having installed a new virtualenv, for example called ENV, if I type

```
. /path/to/ENV/bin/activate

python
import os
print os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

Then I see the `/path/to/ENV/`

However, if I type

```
/path/to/ENV/bin/python
```

And then

```
import os
print os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

I've got a key error
So what is the fundamental difference between these two methods?
Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the script at `bin/activate`, there's a line that looks like this:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/me/.envs/myenv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Which is what's responsible for setting your `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable. When you don't use activate, that variable never gets exported - so it's not present in `os.environ`.